# How to change the class property of <li> in jQuery tab widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

In my script there is a jQuery tab widget. When I click a tab I want to change the `class` property of the `li` of the active tab to `current`.

How can I do it?

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav-content">
    <li class="current first-li"><a href="#tabs-1">tab 1</a></li>
    <li>tab2</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$("ul.nav-content li").click(function() {
    // ??
})
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$("ul.nav-content li").click(function() {
     //you'll probably want to remove all 'current' classes first
     $(".current").removeClass("current")
     $(this).addClass("current")
})
```

Comment: Note that the question says "*change* the class", not "add another class" (see my answer). However, I think this is probably what they are looking for, so +1.

Comment: @locrizak close corresponding parenthes for click :)

Comment: @James I don;t think they really want to get rid of all the classes on the li because `first-li` looks like it is providing some styles

Comment: @locrizak - I agree, I'm just taking the question as it was written. As I said, I think your answer is what they are looking for, just not what they actually asked for.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$("ul.nav-content li").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("current");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("ul.nav-content li").click(function() {
     $(this).addClass("current");
}
```

You can use `addClass` to add the class. Also you can reference the clicked `li` with the `this` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the appropriate methods: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class using jQuery's [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) method:

```
$("ul.nav-content li").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("current");
});
```

If you want to also remove the class (from whatever currently has `.current` perhaps) you can use [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

However, if you actually want to change the class (not just add one, which is what you've stated in your question), you will have to use [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$("ul.nav-content li").click(function() {
    $(this).attr("class", "current");
});
```

That will change the value of the `class` attribute, rather than appending another class name to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("ul.nav-content li").click(function() {
     $("ul.nav-content li").removeClass("current");
     $(this).addClass("current")
}
```

I guess that we should remove all current class before add current class.

Answer (score 1):

When adding a class to a clicked tab, it's important to do it in a way that when another tab is clicked, the class is removed from the previous one. 
The code below will do that for you:

```
$('ul.nav-content li').click(function(){
    $('ul.nav-content li').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```